# Creating WebApi controller with different verbs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi controller that receives the request Get all entries:

```
public IEnumerable <client> GetAllClients ();
```

I need this same controller method:

```
public IEnumerable <clients> GetMaxPaymentClient ();
```

This method also available on request Get, how do I describe this method and how to call the client page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work having two methods with the same method signature and same HTTP verb at the start of their name in the same controller if you just use the default Web API routing. This operates by convention based on method names and there's no way for it to tell which method you intend to reach using a GET request to your controller.

Ways of differentiating the two methods could be:

1. Add a [route] attribute to one or both of your methods to differentiate them. More detail on this is at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2. E.G. you could add [Route("clients/maxpayment")] to your second method.
2. Move one of the methods to a different controller. This is what I'd recommend if you're writing a REST style API. Max payment sounds like it should be a different resource from just general details for clients
3. Amend the method signature of the methods so that they're different, such as by adding an ID argument to one of them. Web API will be able to handle separate routes for methods like Get() and Get(string id). Presumably this isn't an option for you as I assume you have your desired method signatures already.